# Liberate all data from Google+

Tags: google-plus, export, google-takeout

Now that the final demise of Google+ is imminent, how can I get all of my data out of there? I know I have stuff in there I didn't post anywhere else.

Will that also get the stuff I posted to various Communities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google Takeout](https://www.google.com/settings/takeout) can be used to download data from  most Google services, including Google+. From the [help article](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1045788?hl=en):

> You can download your Google+ content using Google Takeout.
>
> If you want to download your Google+ data, you need to download your data from:
>
> - +1s
> - Google+ Circles
> - Google+ Communities
> - Google+ Stream
>
> Note: If you want to download Google+ Pages content, sign in to Google Takeout as the Google+ Page.

Comment: More required. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Takeout will provide a list of all the URLs of posts, and, for public g+ communities, the Create File from Web Page option in Adobe Acrobat will produce a pdf of all the posts.  A workaround is needed for posts from a private google+ community. I don't (yet) know of one.